# Conditional format cell if row contains one or more blank cells?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Imagine a sheet where column A is names and the other columns contain relevant information for those names.  I want to conditionally format the cells in column A so that if there is a blank cell in that row that should be filled, the name cell will display the conditional formatting; think of it like a "there's missing info for this person" indicator.

Before this gets brought up: while it's trivial to set up conditional formatting to color empty cells, coloring the blank cell itself has proven to be not sufficiently noticeable due to the width of the spreadsheet.

Comment: what do you think about `=COUNTBLANK(<range>)` ?

Comment: ... or even ISBLANK for individual cells.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly as [@mehdi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2991872/mehdi) said. You need to use COUNTBLANK(range).

For conditional format, use the option "Format Cells where this formula is true". My formula in cell A2 is like this:

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(2:2)>0;TRUE;FALSE)
```

After typing it, just change the range where this rule applies and select your range data.

I did it like you can see in the image below (please, note I got spanish version of Excel). In my case, if ANY cell in the row is blank, then it colours with yellow the cell.

[image]

Comment: why the `IF`, maths comparison and true/false? `=COUNTBLANK(2:2)` should do nicely.

Comment: I use IF to make sure the function returns True or False. I had problems in the past but using it this way, zero problems :)

Comment: for most intents and purposes, FALSE is zero on a worksheet. by strict definition, a boolean TRUE is anything that is not FALSE.

Comment: Yes, you are 100% right, I must admit is an habit i got in the past. I can't remember now exactly how it was, but since I started to do conditional format like my example, I have never ever problems, so it became a mania.

Comment: just goes to prove that you can do anything a dozen different ways with [tag:excel].